# SVG clipPath showing black background with transparent fill

Tags: svg, clip-path

For an SVG path having a `fill="transparent"`, it is expected not to be shown anyway.

```
<path d="M 0 40 L 200 40 L 200 70 L 0 70 L 0 40 Z" fill="transparent" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none"></path>
```

It works well if it doesn't have a clip-path as show above, or have a single clip-path.

But **when it has a clip-path also with clip-path, it will show black background**, which is not ideal for my case.

Here's the SVG:

```html
    <svg width="1000" height="800">
     <path id="rect" d="M 0 40 L 200 40 L 200 70 L 0 70 L 0 40 Z" fill="transparent" fill-opacity="1" 
        stroke="none" clip-path="url(#zr-clip-2)"></path>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="zr-clip-2" clip-path="url(#zr-clip-1)">
          <path d="M 30 10 L 50 10 L 50 180 L 30 180 L 30 10 Z" fill="#ff0" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="zr-clip-1">
          <path d="M 40 50 L 60 50 L 60 75 L 40 75 L 40 50 Z" fill="#0f0"></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

I want the path with `id="rect"` to clip with the intersection of `zr-clip-1` and `zr-clip-2` when its fill is not transparent, and show nothing when it's transparent.

But instead, it shows black background and it's not even with the same size as that when fill is red:

```html
<svg width="1000" height="800">
  <path d="M 0 40 L 200 40 L 200 70 L 0 70 L 0 40 Z" fill="transparent" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" clip-path="url(#zr-clip-2)"></path>
  <path d="M 0 40 L 200 40 L 200 70 L 0 70 L 0 40 Z" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" clip-path="url(#zr-clip-2)"></path>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="zr-clip-2" clip-path="url(#zr-clip-1)">
      <path d="M 30 10 L 50 10 L 50 180 L 30 180 L 30 10 Z" fill="#ff0" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none"></path>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="zr-clip-1">
      <path d="M 40 50 L 60 50 L 60 75 L 40 75 L 40 50 Z" fill="#0f0"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I see nothing in the first example. Also fill="transparent" is always a bad idea, use fill="none" instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson It shows nothing in Safari 10.11.1, but shows a black rect in Chrome 60.0. It behaves the same with fill="none" or fill="transparent".

Comment: You can report Chrome bugs here: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson and I found this issue  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659790&q=clip-path&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659790

For the time, you may set `fill=rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.002)` to hide the element.